# SKPhysicsBody not as expected

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have the following code to create a rectangular brick and a physics body associated with it. I expected the physics body to be a solid rectangle same size and position as that of the brick, but am getting a body which I think has a poition offset and perhaps also a size difference. Is there some issue with the coordinate systems I have missed? What is the right way to approach this?

```
- (void)addBrick {
    SKShapeNode *brick = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];

    CGRect brickBoundary = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    brick.position = CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0);
    brick.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(brickBoundary, nil);

    brick.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(100.0,100.0)];
    brick.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
    brick.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    brick.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    [self addChild:brick]; 
}
```

Comment: size must be half that of frame.size because body rectangle size is the width/height from center to either side, not the total width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy way to create a rect and add a physics body to it.

```
SKSpriteNode *n1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blueColor] size:objectSize];
n1.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, 200);
n1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:n1.size];
n1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
[self addChild:n1];
```

Here is a modified version from a [RW](http://www.raywenderlich.com) tutorial to provide your spite with a debug rect

```
// RW Debug modified version
CGPathRef bodyPath = CGPathCreateWithRect( CGRectMake(-n1.size.width/2, -n1.size.height/2, n1.size.width, n1.size.height),nil);
SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode node];
shape.path = bodyPath;
shape.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
shape.lineWidth = 1.0;
[n1 addChild:shape];
CGPathRelease(bodyPath);
```

You implementation produced this (red being the physics box).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked :). But do you know where is the problem with my implementation?

Comment: this fixes your implementation CGRect brickBoundary = CGRectMake(-50, -50, 100.0, 100.0); I assume its because spriteNodes have no anchor point so its set at 0,0 ? I aint totally sure sorry.

Comment: yeah, i think the problem is with the anchor point too... Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, it's a great solution. I have updated your code and implemented for a circle. Anybody having troubles about it can check out my blog post: http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/aligning-skphysicsbody-correctly-with-skshapenode/